# Find palindrome with algorithm

Tags: c++

I am given a number N<=200 and I need to find palindrom using ONLY this algorithm and output the palindrom and number of iterations:

1)Reverse nember

2)Revers number + previous one

Examples:

> > 1) N=99
>
> Out 99 0
>
> > 2) N=69
>
> 69+96=165 165+561=726 726+627=1353 1353+3531=4884
>
> Out:4884 4

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int rev(int a)
{
    int b = 0;
    while (a)
    {
        b = 10 * b + a % 10;
        a /= 10;
    }

    return b;
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    int n, c = 0;
    cin >> n;
    while (n != rev(n))
    {
        n = n + rev(n);
        c++;
    }
    cout << n << endl << c;
    return 0;
}
```

It works only for 70 tests out of 100:(

Can you help me so that it works for all tests?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It works but its really bad

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: `n != rev(n)` isn't it enough to just check this condition once and if true you have a palindrome, if false you don't?

Comment: Do the failing tests have anything in common? A trailing zero perhaps?

Comment: Testing system give me only result Yes or No and fails are all over the log

Comment: You need to show us the failing tests (if they are someone else's secret tests, try writing your own...)

Comment: What's the maximum number that could be valid input? Are negative numbers allowed?

Comment: I have tried about 20 tests and wrote tham on paper. If I was correct all tests works fine.

Comment: Range of input: 0<N<=200

Comment: Sounds like you need to go through the numbers 0 to 200 by hand and find the one that your code does not certify.

Comment: It is simply a problem of int overflow. I have it works with `unsigned long long`. For example, for n = 196, the result is 16623445888854432661, for 226 iterations

Comment: Well 196 is a problem number because noone hasnt found the palindrome for that number.

Comment: @Damien If you write it and message me I'll upvote.

Comment: @Gideon You knew that your code wouldn't work with 196 and you're still asking for help? Getting it working for 196 first seems like that would be helpful.

Comment: @Jonathan Mee The program is posted. Works for me, with internal testing. Gideon complains that the site indicates some errors ... Will you have the occasion to test this program?

Comment: @Damien Looks good, have a +1.

Comment: @ Jonathan Mee thank you, but there is still a problem. I discovered that unsigned long long is not enough !! I am currently trying to implement  __int128.

Comment: I tried solving for 196 with Python, which has unlimited size integers. I stopped it after 10000 iterations, it had generated a number with 4159 digits. I'm guessing it never converges.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a problem of integer overflow. A first implementation was realized with unsigned long long. It seemed to work but some overflows were not detected.

A new implementation was performed with __int128. Moreover, a signed version was used in order to be able to detect overflow easily.

Now, for n between 1 and 200, all palindromes are found, except for n = 196, for which an overflow is detected.

Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>

//using namespace std;

void print128 (__int128 a) {
    __int128 v64 = (__int128) 1 << 64;
    __int128 high128 = a / v64;
    __int128 low128 = a % v64;
    unsigned long long high =  high128;
    unsigned long long low =  low128;
    if (high > 0) std::cout << high;
    std::cout << low;
}

__int128 rev(__int128 a) {
    __int128  b = 0;
    while (a) {
    b = 10 * b + a % 10;
    a /= 10;
    }
    return b;
}

int main() {
    //std::ios::sync_with_stdio(0);

    int nerr = 0;
    int cmax = 100000;
    for (int n0 = 10; n0 <= 200; n0++) {
        bool overf = false;
        int c = 0;
        __int128  nrev;
        __int128 n = n0;
        while ((n != (nrev = rev(n))) && (c < cmax)) {
            if (nrev < 0) overf = true;
            n = n + nrev;
            if (n < 0) overf = true;
            c++;
        }
        std::cout << "n = " << n0 << " ";;
        if ((c == cmax) && !overf) {
            std::cout << " ERR0R\n";
            nerr++;
        } else if (overf) {
            std::cout << " OVERFLOW\n";
            nerr++;
        } else {            
            std::cout << " palym = ";
            print128 (n);
            std::cout << "  c = " << c << "\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Nbre of errors = " << nerr << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The question is "what to do for the 196 case ?" We don't know if a solution exists, i.e. if there is convergence. Moreover, if it converges, we don't know what the size of the palindrome could be. Trying to use `int` with more bits can be a long race. What is better will be to implement a dedicated int type adapted to the problem, i.e. a vector of int, each int between 0 and 9. We only have two operations to perform for this algorithm, calculating a palindrome and an addition. Calculating a palindrome will be trivial, inverse the elements of the vector (ignoring first zeros), and an addition will be rather easy to implement. Moreover, such an addition will easily detect overflow. Last but not least, the size of the vector could be adaptable for each `n` value, until a given limit.

EDIT: In a comment, Mark Ransom provided a link to Wikipedia page on Lychrel numbers, i.e. numbers for which the algorithm will not converge. 196 is the lowest and most famous "candidate Lychrel" number. It is conjectured, not proved, that 196 is such a number. Experiments have been performed until billions of digits, not finding a convergence for this number.

Comment: now its 71+ and 29-

Comment: Yeah I used it and 81+ 19-. Its secret tests so I dont know them

Comment: I found that long long is not enough. I have implemented the algo with __int128. However, it requires to have gcc. Do you have it ?

Comment: Damien, have a look at my comment on the question. I'm afraid even int128 won't be close to enough.

Comment: @Mark Ransom My program with int128  shows an overflow for 196. It is why I proposed an implementation of a specific type to test it, see the end of my post. But you made the test with Python. Maybe it is necessary to increase the number of iterations. I made a research on internet, could not find an answer on the convergence

Comment: @Damien I found an answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number

Comment: @Mark Ransom Thank you very much. I will edit my answer